# Python3 nao aceita file.name

Tags: python-3.x

Estou com um script onde quero pegar o nome de cada arquivo junto a primeira linha dentro de cada arquivo e passar esses dos em uma lista dentro de um txt.

```
#modifica titulos de arquivos
import os
import glob

s=("-")

arq=open("listapdf.txt","w")
for file in glob.glob('*.pdf'):
    f = str(file.name)
    fr = str(file.readline())
    arq.write(f+s+fr)
    arq.write("\n")
exception (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError)
pass
```

na saida aponta o seguinte erro:

```
 h1k3rpath@h1k3rpath-Ubuntu:~/Downloads/recovery/sabadoroadsec/pdf$
 python3 lista.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "lista.py",
 line 9, in <module>
     f = str(file.name) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Já alterei e refiz a chamada com *`str`* e sem *`str`*

ja tentei usar a keyword ao inves de nomear variante, tentei algumas outras coisas, mas ainda nao consigo contornar esse erro.

Não estou usando de forma correta o `file.name` ou tem outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação do Python3 (https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) **glob.glob** retorna uma lista de strings. Strings não possuem o atributo **.name**.

Esse é o erro do seu código.

Ao invés de utilizar

```
f = str(file.name)
```

Utilize apenas

```
f = file
```

Comment: e como faço p conseguir o nome do arquivo?

Comment: Como você jjá está utilizando glob.glob, o nome do arquivo é a variável file do seu loop for

Comment: vou testar e já retorno

Comment: o mesmo erro agora apontou p o file.readline(). como faço para pegar a primeira linha do arquivo?

Comment: Então... a variável file contain o nome do arquivo. Para ler o arquivo você precisa abri-lo. Para isso, utilize o método OPEN, igual você fez com a variável arq.

Comment: nao deu certo. se deixo dentro da estrutura do glob, ele aponta problema de str, se deixo antes da estrutura, ou seja, fora da estrutura do for, ele aponta 'file is not defined'

Comment: #modifica titulos de arquivos
import os
import glob

s=("-")

arq=open("listapdf.txt","w")
for file in glob.glob('*.pdf'):
    f = open(file)
    fr = str(file.readline())
    arq.write(f+s+fr)
    arq.write("\n")
exception (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError)
pass

Comment: o mesmo erro de string. acho que agr teria que rever toda a estrutura da logica por conta do glob, que eu nao sabia desses atributos do glob